# Idle user when tasks are disabled/enabled with @tag

Tags: locust

I have 2 users with each assigned specific set of taskSets. When I run locust with --tag option with only 1 of the Taskset chosen, the second user will not have any tasks to run. It throws an error `Exception: No tasks defined on AdminUser...` See sample code below:

```
@tag('AdminPage1')
class AdminPage1(SequentialTaskSet):
    @task
    def admin_task1(self):
        ...
    ...

@tag('UserPage1')
class UserPage1(SequentialTaskSet):
    @task
    def admin_task1(self):
        ...
    ...
    
class AdminUser(HttpUser):
    tasks = [AdminPage1]
  
class EndUser(HttpUser):
    tasks = [UserPage1]
```

`$ locust --users 2 --tag UserPage1`

Is there another way I should be using the tag feature? What I need is to be able to choose which tasks are executed at execution time. I can see one way to make the error go away is to use just 1 user class for all tasksets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error is thrown when locust detect that there is no task property defined in the Locust User class but in this case I think that it's because the TaskSet tags are filtered by the tags specified on the command-line argument and also not checked that there is no tags available to run for the User and the TaskSet

From my PoV it's a bug and it's better if you report it at https://github.com/locustio/locust/issues