# No User class found when run on MacOSx?

Tags: locust

I used locust 1.4.2 on Mac and when i used `TaskSet` i got this error  `Apples-MacBook-Pro.local/ERROR/locust.main: No User class found!`. How can I solved this problem?

python version `3.6.5`

```py
from locust import TaskSet, between, task
class Test(TaskSet):

@task
def just_test(self):
    print("Hello world")
```

Comment: Can you provide more context? The full stack trace and your code, if possible, would be helpful. You can create a new simple locustfile and see if you can reproduce with that if you can't share your original.

Comment: Please provide the execution context and everything that others could help you to solve the issue. Also see if your issue have something related to this one
https://github.com/locustio/locust/issues/1689

Comment: posible related with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65764666/idle-user-when-tasks-are-disabled-enabled-with-tag/65781685#65781685

Comment: i've edited question. Please, look at the question again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace TaskSet with HttpUser. A TaskSet always belongs to a User.